# Read in CLI argumnet, then use regex's to look for it. -Python

Tags: python, regex

Sorry if this is probably a simple fix but I can't think of one. I am trying to take a command line argument (in this case a name) and search through a file hierarchy and keep track of the number of times that name comes up. I was just wondering how to store the CL input and then search through files using a regular expression with that input as my search key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import os
the_name= sys.argv[1]
count=0
for r,d,f in os.walk("/mypath"):
    for file in f:
        if the_name in file:
            count+=1
```

If you want to search IN the file themselves,

```
for r,d,f in os.walk("/mypath"):
    for file in f:
        for line in open(os.path.join(r,file)) :
            if the_name in line:  
                count+=line.count(the_name)
```

Comment: Will this search through each file, or just the file names?

Comment: what does the "d" do in `r,d,f`?

Comment: just a place holder for directories returned by `os.walk()`, please read the `os` module doc to find out.